# Deploy NodeJS server on Heroku : Error: Cannot find module '@prisma/client'

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, deployment

I built a website from a front-end application (Vite + VueJS) and a back-end application (NodeJS, ExpressJS).

I try to deploy them distinctly using Heroku following the official documentation.

First, I deployed the client from a GitHub repository and creating "server.js", "Procfile" files. It worked pretty well.

I followed the same process for my backend application. Once the deployment is finalized on Heroku, I navigate to the URL of my website and I get an error.

```js
// app.ts

import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

import config from "config";
import createServer from "./server/createServer";

const port = process.env.PORT || config.get<number>("port");
const clientUri = config.get<string>("clientUri");
const app = createServer();

app.listen(port, async () => {
  console.info(`Server is running on ${clientUri}`);
});

// package.json

"scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/app.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "postinstall": "npx prisma generate && npx prisma db push && tsc",

// Procfile

web: node build/app.js
```

I will be grateful if someone more experienced can tell me where the error comes from. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention you have the app.js in this destination: `node build/app.js`
but when you run the code on Heroku it runs the code from: `app/app.js`
I don't know Heroku, but I think you should change the `app.js` address in setting.

Comment: I don't know where "app" comes from. I don't have such a file in my folder.

Comment: Maybe you should add ```web: npm run build && node build/app.js```  to Procfile

Comment: I finally solved the issue. The problem came from "package.json". It was related with the ORM I used which is Prisma. Thanks for your help.